# Как в аннотации типов указать, что тип должен реализовывать какой-то конкретный метод?

Tags: python, типы-данных, аннотации

Как в аннотации типов указать, что тип должен реализовывать какой-то конкретный метод?

Чаще всего это нужно для специальных методов (например, `__gt__` означает что объекты можно сравнивать через оператор `>`).

К примеру, мы пишем функцию `get_max` (упрощённый аналог встроенной функции `max`):

```py
def get_max(l: list[...]) -> ...:
    cond = l[0]
    for cur in l:
        if cur > cond:
            cond = cur
    return cond
```

На месте `...` должна быть аннотация типа, показывающая, что тип поддерживает сравнение с помощью оператора `>` (больше). Какой она должна быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии Python3.8 ([PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)) доступен такой способ:

Сначала нужно определить класс, наследующий от `typing.Protocol` и реализующий нужный метод:

```py
class SupportsGreaterThan(typing.Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, other): ...
```

Потом определить такой `TypeVar`:

```py
GT = typing.TypeVar('GT', bound=SupportsGreaterThan)
```

И, наконец, использовать его в своей функции:

```py
def get_max(l: list[GT]) -> GT:
    ...  # Реализация такая же
```

После всех этих действий Mypy предупреждает о неверном типе:

При таком коде:

```py
get_max([1, 2, 3])
get_max([None, None])  # None нельзя сравнивать с помощью оператора `>`!
```

Он выводит:

```
main.py:20: error: Value of type variable "GT" of "get_max" cannot be "None"  [type-var]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```